# Multiple SUM fields

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT: The code works, my bad, i was searching in the wrong date column and the SQL database needed adjustments. Thanks again for the help!**

---

I have multiple columns that I need to `SUM` and one specifically that has a = to a specific word. The reason why I don't have multiple queries is because I want to display a table in PHP.

When I run the last part it shows up incorrectly for me:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN STATS = 'cancel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cancel_stats
```

Full code:

```
SELECT suppportrep,

(SELECT SUM(
SUM(option1 IS NOT NULL and option1 <> '') +

SUM(option2 IS NOT NULL and option2 <> '') + 
SUM(option3 IS NOT NULL and option3 <> '')
))  AS total1, 

   SUM(option1 IS NOT NULL and option1 <> '') as option1,
   SUM(option2 IS NOT NULL and option2 <> '') as option2,
   SUM(option3 IS NOT NULL and option3 <> '') as option3,

   SUM(CASE WHEN STATS = 'cancel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cancel_stats

FROM salestable 
where date2 >= '2016/04/01' 
AND   date2 <= '2016/04/21'
     GROUP BY supportrep
     ORDER BY total1 DESC
```

[Here is the example of the output, the cancel_stats area is pulling up numbers that are confusing to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmTfJ.jpg)

Comment: You may get a better answer if you provided a sample of what your table data looks like, and what you are expecting to get as a result of your query.

Comment: The cancel_stats area is not showing correctly

edit: Sorry click enter to quick

Comment: @DevonC: how can we tell it's not correct? Please post the result you see and the result you expect to see.

Comment: Please, consider providing sample data in a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: And please, add it to your question, not as a comment.. It might be best if you read over this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry trying to grab that data for you

Comment: Since `SUM(CASE WHEN STATS = 'cancel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cancel_stats,` is the last select statement, it should not have a trailing comma; this should trigger a syntax error. Are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: Sorry David, i removed that part of the code before posting it here. I don't have the comma there in the actual code (i'll edit this right now)

Comment: What is your sample input? Also, and this may be a personal thing, but I usually find it a lot better to include any relative data as text in your question rather than linking off to an image. Here is a recently posted question, and while it is a little short on information itself, it does provide an example of input and desired output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781976/find-non-duplicate-records-excluding-nulls-based-on-one-field

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Sorry i was looking in the wrong date column and it needed adjustment on the MYSQL side. New to the site and loved the quick responses, also will be reading the "how to ask" and will make sure to be more detailed next time.

Comment: There's a lot of good information on there to help you write a solid, focused question. The better formed your question, the better the chance of people willing to spend time helping you out.